# ASP.NET MVC Signalr reconnect and negotiate throwing a System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, signalr, application-pool, web-garden

I have an ASP.NET MVC application working on a Web Garden configuration. The application pool identity is set to a custom domain account (with local administator permissions). Application pool has 4 worker processes. Session state mode is set to serverState using the ASP.NET State service which runs on the same machine (not remote one).

Regarding to signalr I have noticed an OutOfMemoryException in the event log when trying to reconnect and negotiate and I am not being able to detect what is happening. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Some texts below in the errors are in Spanish (Sorry).

Below the reconnect error:

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: Excepción no controlada. 
Event time: 05/11/2020 13:28:04 
Event time (UTC): 05/11/2020 12:28:04 
Event ID: 447eb425512c433387a36b70af64f768 
Event sequence: 1 
Event occurrence: 1 
Event detail code: 0 
 
Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-2-132490528843179653 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyMVCApp\ 
    Machine name: MyServer 
 
Process information: 
    Process ID: 1668 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: MyDomain\MyAppPoolCustomIdentity 
 
Exception information: 
    Exception type: InvalidOperationException 
    Exception message: El método de inicialización Run previo al inicio de la aplicación del tipo WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager produjo una excepción con el siguiente mensaje de error: Se produjo una excepción de tipo 'System.OutOfMemoryException'..
   en System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures)
   en System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods)
   en System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded)
   en System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart()
   en System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)

Se produjo una excepción de tipo 'System.OutOfMemoryException'.
   en System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   en System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   en System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   en System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   en System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile)
   en WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.get_Assemblies()
   en WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.RunActivationMethods[T](Boolean designerMode)
   en WebActivatorEx.ActivationManager.Run()

 
 
Request information: 
    Request URL: http://my.mvcapp.com/signalr/reconnect?transport=longPolling&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=6Avu6HS5DNT2tKAPHT90nO3u8M2arqOCtaMVIGGiEi/ZsxSM3axZQUBukhn1C0p14qGfoIxy722kR3LhvsZb5Qq6ERwk8z9GA6DI4VGJ8fm8onV8pM79bGp2BTIwaareiiXFYGIWDJxWL7LKux6TwA==&connectionData=[{"name":"wstimerhub"}] 
    Request path: /signalr/reconnect 
    User host address: XXX.XX.X.XX 
    User:  
    Is authenticated: False 
    Authentication Type:  
    Thread account name: MyDomain\MyAppPoolCustomIdentity
 
Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 51 
    Thread account name: MyDomain\MyAppPoolCustomIdentity
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    en System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures)
   en System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods)
   en System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded)
   en System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart()
   en System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)
 
 
Custom event details:
```

And below the signalr negotitate error (Event id 1309):

```
Event code: 3005 
Event message: Excepción no controlada. 
Event time: 05/11/2020 18:09:47 
Event time (UTC): 05/11/2020 17:09:47 
Event ID: c19a08970c4c44abb969098d601bc6e1 
Event sequence: 13649 
Event occurrence: 2 
Event detail code: 0 
 
Application information: 
    Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-4-132490644058804577 
    Trust level: Full 
    Application Virtual Path: / 
    Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyMVCApp\ 
    Machine name: MyServer 
 
Process information: 
    Process ID: 6936 
    Process name: w3wp.exe 
    Account name: MyDomain\MyAppPoolCustomIdentity  
 
Exception information: 
    Exception type: OutOfMemoryException 
    Exception message: Se produjo una excepción de tipo 'System.OutOfMemoryException'.
   en System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ReadRequestHeaders()
   en System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.GetKnownRequestHeader(Int32 index)
   en System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest.HasEntityBody()
   en System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEncodingFromHeaders()
   en System.Web.HttpRequest.get_ContentEncoding()
   en System.Web.HttpRequest.get_QueryStringEncoding()
   en System.Web.HttpRequest.get_QueryStringText()
   en System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
   en System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)

 
 
Request information: 
    Request URL: http://my.mvcapp.com/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=[{"name":"wstimerhub"}]&_=1604596208232 
    Request path: /signalr/negotiate 
    User host address: XXX.XX.XXX.XX 
    User: MyDomain\OneUser
    Is authenticated: True 
    Authentication Type: Negotiate 
    Thread account name: MyDomain\MyAppPoolCustomIdentity  
 
Thread information: 
    Thread ID: 86 
    Thread account name: MyDomain\MyAppPoolCustomIdentity 
    Is impersonating: False 
    Stack trace:    en System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.ReadRequestHeaders()
   en System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest.GetKnownRequestHeader(Int32 index)
   en System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest.HasEntityBody()
   en System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEncodingFromHeaders()
   en System.Web.HttpRequest.get_ContentEncoding()
   en System.Web.HttpRequest.get_QueryStringEncoding()
   en System.Web.HttpRequest.get_QueryStringText()
   en System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
   en System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)
 
 
Custom event details:
```

Comment: You can use debug diagnostic tool to capture data of applications running in IIS, generate dmp files after capture, and use debug diag analysis to analyze the files. Then find the cause of outofmemory.

Comment: @BruceZhang Could you provide the link to download Debug Diagnostic tool? I am worried to use this tool since I need to debug in production environment and I do not know if this tool consumes a lot of resources of the server (and consequently affecting the performace and responsiveness of my ASP.NET MVC application)

Comment: You can download from this link:https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58210  .It won't consumes a lot of resources.